# CSS flexbox horizontal timeline

Tags: html, css, timeline

I am trying to make a flexbox horizontal timeline

I got the idea of apply a `:nth-child(2n) { transform: translateY(100%); }` but I run into a huge number of issues to take it work:

- Content before the timeline go inside of the timeline (without a way to clear them)
- Adding an `overflow-x: auto;` to the parent automatically adds an `overflow-y` too and if you hide the `overflow-y` then just the half of timeline is visible

There is another way to make it possible with flexboxes? I tried with margins too, but items position is not well centered

```css
@import "compass/css3";

.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  
  display: flex;
  
  /* This line make an undesired Y scrollbar */
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;

  color: white;
  
  display: flex;
  align-self: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(2n) {
  align-self: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-start;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}


/* Random heights for testing */
.flex-item:nth-child(5) {
  height: 100px;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(3) {
  height: 200px;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(4) {
  height: 100px;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(6) {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This text is ok, but there is an undesired Y scrollbar on the timeline</p>
</div>

<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item"><span>text</span></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><span>text</span></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><span>text</span></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><span>text</span></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><span>text</span></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><span>text</span></li>
</ul>

<div>
  <p>This text should go after the timeline</p>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean with "content before the timeline go inside" ?

Comment: Hi rebecca, Check the example code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aLjEdo How the half of the timeline is translated using `transform: translateY(100%);` I am unable to make the height of bottom elements detected

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: I added the snippet code using your function and updated it to make this more clear, hope it now be more clear

Answer (score 0):

Here is a lame but working solution ;-)

Add it as first child to the flexbox (you should tidy this up though).

You can use `position:absolute/relative` if you want it to overlay on top of the time line instead of before it.

```css
@import "compass/css3";
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  /* Uncomment this line to see the issue */
  /*overflow-x: auto;*/
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-self: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(2n) {
  align-self: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-start;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}


/* Random heights for testing */

.flex-item:nth-child(5) {
  height: 100px;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(3) {
  height: 200px;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(4) {
  height: 100px;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(6) {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
  <div style="clear: both;">
    <p>This text should go before</p>
  </div>
  <li class="flex-item"><span>text</span></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><span>text</span></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><span>text</span></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><span>text</span></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><span>text</span></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><span>text</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Joel, thanks but code example text is wrong, I do not want the text before, I want it after the timeline but how it is translated bottom height is not detected, also I got an unwanted Y scroll bar, that i am investigating to remove

Comment: pls make a jpg and add it in your question of what you exactly want it is every unclear. i  tried my best to show what i thought you wanted.

Comment: Hi Joel, you are right, first code example is wrong, I updated it, but my main issue comes from the Y scrollbar automatically added when I tried to set just `overflow-x: auto;` and the impossibility to let content next to the timeline be positioned before it

Answer (score 0):

Since your moving your items down with `translateY` you need to position everything that comes after accordingly

I just added a class `other_content` to your div, set `position:relative`and `top:200px`

Although you need to keep in mind to adjust the `top` value, depending on how big your items get

```css
.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;

  color: white;
  
  display: flex;
  align-self: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(2n) {
  align-self: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-start;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}


/* Random heights for testing */
.flex-item:nth-child(5) {
  height: 100px;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(3) {
  height: 200px;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(4) {
  height: 100px;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(6) {
  height: 200px;
}
.other_content{
  position:relative;
  top:200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This text is ok, but there is an undesired Y scrollbar on the timeline</p>
</div>

<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item"><span>text</span></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><span>text</span></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><span>text</span></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><span>text</span></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><span>text</span></li>
  <li class="flex-item"><span>text</span></li>
</ul>

<div class="other_content">
  <p>This text should go after the timeline</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You are required to post your code and markup for your answer here, not a third party site which can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one and making your answer useless. Also, do not answer off topic questions such as this one that does not supply the required code either. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions

Comment: ah, sorry, when i answered it didn't show as off-topic. And i thought adding the line about the added class and attributes would suffice. I'll keep that in mind for the future

Comment: Any question that does not show code or markup that illustrates the problem here on SO is off topic and will be closed eventually.

Comment: well it was open for 45 mins, so mistake's happen

Comment: It does not matter. Questions and answers without code are off topic and will be closed. Sometimes it just takes a while for us to find it.

Comment: Hey Rob I already added the snippet from SO, so could you unmark this as off topic? Thanks in advance